# Find CPU usgae in a multicore PC

Tags: powershell, wmi, multicore

How we can find the CPU usage and other properties of a multicore PC using powershell or WMI.

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get-WmiObject` commandlet for this purpose. Below command will give you current CPU load

```
Get-WmiObject win32_processor | select LoadPercentage  |fl
```

If you just use `Get-WmiObject win32_processor`; it will list out all the properties one can check like

```
Get-WmiObject win32_processor | select NumberOfCores
```

Comment: Won't there be multiple values for LoadPercentage, if its a Multicore PC?

Comment: @SebastianXavier, You will get the average CPU load percentage but don't think for a particular core though. Also, consider accepting the answer if it's helpful.

Comment: This only gives you the utilization of the 1st core. 
You can check this by running a cpu burn in utility on a single core at a time to verify.